# Magento 2.1 - Add prefix to category url

Tags: magento-2.1, category, url

How to add a prefix for Magento 2.1 URL and show child without a parent?

`Example: Category level1: www.example.com/categories/fashion.html`

`Example: Category level2: www.example.com/categories/men.html`

`Example: Category level3: www.example.com/categories/tshirt.html`

Comment: Will this site only ever be in one language?

Comment: Yes it is @DominicXigen